# php - header location - wrong url opening

Tags: php, redirect

Script:

```
https://example.com/docs/index.php
```

In index.php, I have the following code:

```
header('Location: page2.php');
```

However, instead of opening page2.php, the following URL is opened:

```
https://example.com/docs/index.php/page2.php
```

If I put an absolute URL, everything works.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there any workaround so that I don't have to use an absolute URL?

Comment: are using any framework ?

Comment: are you sure that the script isn't `https://example.com/docs/index.php/`? btw, the location header require a complete absolute URI

Comment: `header('Location: /docs/page2.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php